# Python3, read line by line from txt file and split line into two variables

Tags: python

Say i have a text file containing this:

```
harry:arnold
james:king
jim:lin
reece:inter
```

How do i read line by line from this text file and split from the : and put the firstname and lastname into different values, i have previous code like this:

```
with open(filepath) as fp:
    lines = fp.read().splitlines()
with open(filepath, "w") as fp:
    for line in lines:
```

How would i add, for example, firstname = harry, lastname = arnold throughout the entire txt file

Comment: `'reece:inter'.split(':')` would split the string into `'reece'` and `'inter'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `readlines` to read the text then iterate through the text

```
with open(filepath, 'r') as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()
for x in lines:
    sp = x.split(":")
    firstname, lastname = sp[0], sp[1]
    print(firstname,lastname)
```

Comment: This works, but is also printing a space at the end of each value, how would i remove this

Comment: you need to strip the data in that case, use this `sp = x.strip().split(":")`

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the file and break at the colon.

```
with open(filepath, 'r') as fp:
    result = []
    while 1:
        line = fp.readline()
        if len(line) == 0: #end of file break
            break
        result.append(line.split(':'))

print(result)
```